dynamically bind and call parent component method from child component in angular
I am getting error on tabMethod is not function child component
In the Parent component:
In the .ts file:
this.pillTabs = [
    { tabName: 'Subscribers', tabMethod: this.showSubscribers.bind(this) },
    { tabName: 'Exemplars', tabMethod: this.showExemplars.bind(this) }
];

In the .html file:
<pill-tabs [pillTabs]="pillTabs"></pill-tabs>

In the Child component:
In the .ts file:
@Input() pillTabs: any;

In the .html file:
 <div *ngFor="let pillTab of pillTabs; let i = index">
        <input type="radio" id="{{'radio-' + i}}" name="tabs" [checked]="pillTab.checked"
            (click)="pillTab.tabMethod()" />
        <label class="tab" for="{{'radio-' + i}}">{{pillTab.tabName}}</label>
    </div>


issue not reproducible please replicate and share in the question -> stackblitz
